# merging array of objects that contain an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

hello i want to know how can i achieve this approach:
i have this array of objects:

```
const array =[{district:1,buildings:["1","2"]},{district:1,buildings:["1","3"]},{district:2,buildings:["1","2"]}]
```

i want to merge the objects of the array + merging the buildings of the object with same district.

what should i get :

```
const array =[{district:1,buildings:["1","2","3"]},{district:2,buildings:["1","2"]}]
```

any help. thanks

note: this is can be done with for loop but i am looking for simpler approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution, which:

- does not overwrite / change the original array
- is fully functional

Explanation:

1. Use `array.reduce(..)` to reduce the list to only two unique entries (district 1 and 2) that has a (possibly) non-unique list of buildings each.
2. Use `Object.entries(..).map(..)` to be able to iterate the districts in order to make the buildings property unique.

```js
 const array = [
  { district: 1, buildings: [ '1', '2' ] },
  { district: 1, buildings: [ '1', '3' ] },
  { district: 2, buildings: [ '1', '2' ] }
];
 
 const result = Object.entries(
  array.reduce(
    (acc, {district, buildings}) => {
        acc[district] = acc[district] ? acc[district] : []; 
        acc[district].push(...buildings);
        return acc;
    }, 
    []
  )
).map(m => ({district: parseInt(m[0]), buildings: [...new Set(m[1])]}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to create an object which will store all values for a particular district(district will be keys)

After this, you will have an object with keys as districts and value as building array. Then you can recreate an array using an `Array.prototype.map` and set to remove duplicates.

```js
const array = [{
    district: 1,
    buildings: ["1", "2"]
  },
  {
    district: 1,
    buildings: ["1", "3"]
  },
  {
    district: 2,
    buildings: ["1", "2"]
  }
];

let mapped_array = array.reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val.district] = acc[val.district] ?
    acc[val.district].concat(val.buildings) :
    val.buildings;
  return acc;
}, {});

mapped_array = Object.keys(mapped_array).map(val => {
  return {
    district: val,
    buildings: [...new Set(mapped_array[val])]
  };
});

console.log(mapped_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
const array = [{district:1,buildings:["1","2"]},{district:1,buildings:["1","3"]},{district:2,buildings:["1","2"]}];

function merge(arr){

  let result = [];
  
   arr.forEach(item => {
    if(result[item.district]){
       item.buildings.forEach(val => {result[item.district].add(val)});
    } else {
       result[item.district] = new Set(item.buildings);
    }
  })
  
  return result.filter(item => item).map((item,i) => {return {district: i + 1, buidings: [...item]}});

}

console.log(merge(array));
```

Comment: good one! but i am still looking  for simpler method. anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Loops are good, however here's an approach using a few built in methods:

```
const array =[{district:1,buildings:["1","2"]},{district:1,buildings:["1","3"]},{district:2,buildings:["1","2"]}]

var result = {}; //will store our results, object/dict used for optimal indexing
array.map(function(row){ //for each row in the array
    //if we have no existing record of it, we will store that record
   if(!result[row.district])result[row.district]=row;
   else{
      //since we have an existing record we will modify it
      //for each building num in the new record
      row["buildings"].map(function(buildingNum){
            //if the building number doesn't exist in the existing record
           if(result[row.district]['buildings'].indexOf(buildingNum)==-1){
               result[row.district]['buildings'].push(buildingNum) //add it
           }
      })

   }
})
result=Object.values(result) //convert our result back to an array
```